# How to use date range in python to pull /query data using time and date

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, python-datetime

Below is my code that is grabbing data and converting the data into a CSV file (this is working). I am trying to only focus on the data that is returned from midnight till 4pm (BST (British Summer Time) UTC/GMT +1 hour) using the dates some how.

Could someone show me how this is done please, DTDT is the date.

If what I am trying to achieve does not make sense, just let me know I will try to explain it.

My Code:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import csv

es = Elasticsearch(["9200"])

# Replace the following Query with your own Elastic Search Query
res = es.search(index="search", body=
                {
                    "_source": ["DTDT", "TRDT", "SPLE", "RPLE"],
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "should": [
                                {"wildcard": {"CN": "TEST1"}}

                            ]
                        }
                    }
}, size=10)



header_names = { 'DTDT': 'DATE', 'TRDT': 'TIME', ...}

with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'w') as f:  # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
    header_present  = False
    for doc in res['hits']['hits']:
        my_dict = doc['_source'] 
        if not header_present:
            w = csv.DictWriter(f, my_dict.keys())
            w.writerow(header_names)  # will write DATE, TIME, ... in correct place
            header_present = True


        w.writerow(my_dict)
```

For example, I want to only return the data from midnight till 2pm (using the current date).

Comment: Can you please share one row of csv file which contains data?

Comment: @ Dinesh, these are example rows in the CSV.

13/10/2017 00:00 f#b422560 0 1001

07/09/2017 16:55 f#b422562 0 1001

05/09/2017 06:24 f#b422576 0 1001

05/09/2017 06:24 f#b422578 0 1001

25/08/2017 12:26 f#b422505 0 1001

13/10/2017 13:24 b#r110576 0 1001
08/09/2017 02:53 b#r110585 0 1001
13/10/2017 14:00 b#r110594 0 1001

For example, when the files is being created i want the current date data from midnight till 6pm, as you can see there are 3 rows that contain todays data and i only want that shown in the file

Comment: @Dinesh, want to have a chat discussion. When i paste the rows the format goes wrong in the comment box. not sure if you can see it correctly

Comment: I got it perfectly !!!

Comment: oh good! thank you for taking a look!

Comment: When you say from midnight till 2 Pm, then you want only 14 hrs data ???

Comment: Yes, that is correct :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156628/discussion-between-dinesh-pundkar-and-rich).

Answer (score 0):

Before writing it into csv file, you can check the time range and then decide to write it in file.

Add below function to check time range :

```
def time_in_range(start, end, x):
    """Return true if x is in the range [start, end]"""
    if start <= end:
        return start <= x <= end
    else:
        return start <= x or x <= end
```

It will True if the given time is in range

Then in your code add this.

```
import datetime
#Range here(Midnight to 2 PM)
start = datetime.time(0,0,0)
end = datetime.time(14,0,0)

with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'w') as f:  # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
    header_present  = False
    for doc in res['hits']['hits']:
        my_dict = doc['_source']
        if not header_present:
            w = csv.DictWriter(f, my_dict.keys())
            w.writerow(header_names)  # will write DATE, TIME, ... in correct place
            header_present = True

        #Get time
        curr_time  = my_dict['DTDT']
        #Conver it into datetime object
        d_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(curr_time, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
        #Check whether it is in range using above function
        #If in range, then it will write to file
        if time_in_range(start, end, d_obj.time()):
            w.writerow(my_dict)
```